# Not Able to Access Local Flask Server Endpoint on a windows 10 Pro machine

Tags: python, windows, flask

Running this code on Windows 10 Pro

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And see the following as a result

```
** * Serving Flask app "test" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 198-193-169
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
**
```

However when I try to open this url `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`
I see the following error on the webpage

`{"error":"Not found"}`

Any idea why this is not working on windows?
Do I need to enable any permissions?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have something else listening on 5000 ? If your app is receiving requests, you must see some logs from your GET request at least.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I listed all the processes listening on 127.0.0.1:5000 by using netstat -ano and was able to find the culprit. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

There was another process listening on the same port. I killed that process and problem was solved for me